# Ответ MySQL: Документация #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql

Случайно удалил пользователей в phpmyadmin, поcле чего в данный ресурс не заходит вообще, выдает ошибку:

> 1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: значит все база и таблицы тоже удолилос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить пользователя обратно

1. В конфигурационном файле my.cnf в секции [mysqld] добавляем следующую опцию:

   ```
   skip-grant-tables
   ```
2. Перезапускаем MySQL
3. Подключаемся к БД без логина и пароля
4. Для восстановления удаленного пользователя root@localhost выполняем следующие команды:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
   ```
5. После проделанных действий выходим из MySQL, удаляем ранее добавленное значение skip-grant-tables в конфигурационном файле my.cnf и еще раз перезапускаем сервис:

Теперь можно подключиться к базе данных с указанного хоста (localhost) под пользователем root используя установленный пароль.